# Getting ajax call to update table

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get an ajax call to update a table (max) on the existing page and it doesn't appear to be working.  I think the issue is in this first page with the function because the following page isn't even getting the parameter I'm passing.  The html table (max) is on this page as well.  Is there something missing from this page?  Or passing the parameter incorrectly?  This is the script i have on the initial page:

```
<a name='top'></a>
        <form action="pool.php">
             Enter ID: <input type="text" name="clientid" id="txclientid">
                <input type="button" name="btclientid" value="Submit">

        </form>
<script> 
$('#btclientid').click(function(){
    $.post('pool.php',{clientid : $(this).val()}, function(response){
        $(max).html(response);

    });
});         
</script>
```

And this is on the pool.php page where I grab the parameter to pass to the query it runs (but it doesn't appear it's even getting this far):

```
$clientid = isset($_POST['clientid']) ? $_POST['clientid'] : NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are passing the Value of the Button, not the text input. I would try something like this...

```
<a name='top'></a>
        <form action="pool.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
             Enter ID: <input type="text" name="clientid" id="txclientid">
                <input type="button" name="btclientid" value="Submit">

        </form>
<script> 
$('#btclientid').click(function(){
    $.post('pool.php',{clientid : $('#txclientid').val()}, function(response){
        $(max).html(response);

    });
});         
</script>
```

I would try something like this:

```
        <a name='top'></a>
                <form action="pool.php" name="poolName" id="poolId" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                     Enter ID: <input type="text" name="clientid" id="txclientid">
                        <input type="button" name="btclientid" value="Submit">

                </form>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#btclientid').click(function(){
          $( "#poolId" ).submit   
        });
    });


    $( "#poolId" ).submit(function( event ) {
// Stop form from leaving page
        event.preventDefault();
//Gather Form Info/set variables
          var form = $(this);
          var url = form.attr('action');
//Post the form with Ajax
          $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: url,
             data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
             success: function(data)
             {
               //What to do on success
               $(max).html(data);
              }
              else{
               //What to do on failure (error messages etc....)
              }
            }
          });
          return;
        }
      });

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: I'm curious why you added `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. That's only when handling files.

Comment: I wasn't sure if you had files or not. I use it as a "Just in case"

Comment: It doesn't hurt to have it in there. I was just saying :)

Comment: Hmm..still no dice.  Some articles mention you may need to "sanitize" the function first?  Or do i need to initialize the function first before the <a name='top'></a> portion?